# Android Studio: "App has stopped" when image view on click in navigation drawer header

Tags: java, android, xml, navigation-drawer

When I click on the `ImageView` on the navigation drawer header to go to the next activity, the app crashed.

Here is the code:

For MainActivity.java:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
//        ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
//        actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
//        actionBar.setIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });

        final DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
        navigationView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, Profile.class));
            }
        });
```

For nav_header_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/nav_header"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/nav_header_height"
    android:background="@drawable/side_nav_bar"
    android:gravity="bottom"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/profile_image"
        android:layout_width="83dp"
        android:layout_height="75dp"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/nav_header_vertical_spacing"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:onClick="onClick"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/profile" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/nav_header_vertical_spacing"
        android:text="Android Studio"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="android.studio@android.com" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Profile.class:

```
public class Profile extends Fragment{
    View myView; //A view object called myView

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        myView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.profile, container, false);
        return myView;
    }
}
```

Logs:

```
11-25 17:30:34.959 6126-6126/? I/zygote: Not late-enabling -Xcheck:jni (already on)
11-25 17:30:35.098 6126-6126/? W/zygote: Unexpected CPU variant for X86 using defaults: x86
11-25 17:30:35.179 6126-6133/? E/zygote: Failed writing handshake bytes (-1 of 14): Broken pipe
11-25 17:30:35.179 6126-6133/? I/zygote: Debugger is no longer active
11-25 17:30:35.791 6126-6126/? I/InstantRun: starting instant run server: is main process
11-25 17:30:36.123 6126-6151/? D/OpenGLRenderer: HWUI GL Pipeline

                                                 [ 11-25 17:30:36.160  6126: 6151 D/         ]
                                                 HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0x9fe29800, tid 6151
11-25 17:30:36.323 6126-6151/com.example.hci I/zygote: android::hardware::configstore::V1_0::ISurfaceFlingerConfigs::hasWideColorDisplay retrieved: 0
11-25 17:30:36.323 6126-6151/com.example.hci I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
11-25 17:30:36.323 6126-6151/com.example.hci D/OpenGLRenderer: Swap behavior 1
11-25 17:30:36.323 6126-6151/com.example.hci W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to choose config with EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED, retrying without...
11-25 17:30:36.323 6126-6151/com.example.hci D/OpenGLRenderer: Swap behavior 0
11-25 17:30:36.325 6126-6151/com.example.hci D/EGL_emulation: eglCreateContext: 0xa28040c0: maj 2 min 0 rcv 2
11-25 17:30:36.327 6126-6151/com.example.hci D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xa28040c0: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xa2803140)
11-25 17:30:36.340 6126-6131/com.example.hci I/zygote: Do partial code cache collection, code=12KB, data=19KB
11-25 17:30:36.342 6126-6131/com.example.hci I/zygote: After code cache collection, code=12KB, data=19KB
11-25 17:30:36.342 6126-6131/com.example.hci I/zygote: Increasing code cache capacity to 128KB
11-25 17:30:36.345 6126-6131/com.example.hci I/zygote: Do partial code cache collection, code=12KB, data=37KB
11-25 17:30:36.345 6126-6131/com.example.hci I/zygote: After code cache collection, code=12KB, data=37KB
11-25 17:30:36.345 6126-6131/com.example.hci I/zygote: Increasing code cache capacity to 256KB
11-25 17:30:36.346 6126-6131/com.example.hci I/zygote: JIT allocated 71KB for compiled code of void android.widget.TextView.<init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int, int)
11-25 17:30:36.346 6126-6131/com.example.hci I/zygote: Compiler allocated 4MB to compile void android.widget.TextView.<init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int, int)
11-25 17:30:36.388 6126-6151/com.example.hci D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xa28040c0: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xa2803140)
11-25 17:30:39.559 6126-6126/com.example.hci D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
11-25 17:30:39.561 6126-6126/com.example.hci E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                        Process: com.example.hci, PID: 6126
                                                                        java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find method onClick(View) in a parent or ancestor Context for android:onClick attribute defined on view class android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView with id 'profile_image'
                                                                            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.resolveMethod(AppCompatViewInflater.java:327)
                                                                            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:284)
                                                                            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6294)
                                                                            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:24770)
                                                                            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:790)
                                                                            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
                                                                            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: why this line    ImageView img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.profile_image); exist in the onlick?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ImageView` in the line:

```
ImageView img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.profile_image);
```

is unused removing it will solve the error in navigation `View`, also remember its `null`.

Also remove the attribute `android:onClick="onClick"` in your xml for the `ImageView` because you have NOT defined any method called `onClick` in your activity.

But using my instincts you want to go another activity(`Profile.class`) when the header is clicked use this:

```
NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
View header_view = navigationView.getHeaderView(0);
ImageView img = (ImageView) header_view.findViewById(R.id.profile_image);
img.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, Profile.class));
        }
    });
```

But if you want to go to another activity only when the (`ImageView`) is clicked do this:

```
NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
View header_view = navigationView.getHeaderView(0);
header_view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, Profile.class));
        }
    });
```

Comment: The app still crashes after i tried using the code u provided

Comment: Where are you debugging your app. If you are using android studio when the app crashes there are some logs in red. but some are in blue! When you click you can see which line brings the crash. Show us which line does it! @user7146946

Comment: And by the way I gave you three alternative codes. Which one causes crash?

Comment: I tried all the three codes, I will add the logs to my questions (for the first code).

Comment: Okay waiting for it!

Comment: I have added it

Comment: Hey the error is not in code then remove this line in XML of the imageView `android:onClick="onClick"`

Comment: I removed, but when i clicked on it, It doesn't go to the next activity page

Comment: From there now check my answer and go to the second or third approach in my answer see above!

Comment: I tried using the third approach, when on click, it went to the main page of the emulator. Is this because the `Profile.class` is a fragment?

Comment: Oooh sorry you did not tell me that the `Profile.class` is a fragment. We do not go to a fragment like that fragment are reusable and only used inside an activity. I think we need to chat also! lets go chatting!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159799/discussion-between-xenolion-and-user7146946).

Answer (score 0):

The problem is here in this code
just remove the image view from the onclick

```
NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
    navigationView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
//remove below image view line
            ImageView img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.profile_image);
            startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, Profile.class));
        }
    });
```

and the reason for this is that image view you are getting is inside navigation view not in your main xml.

Answer (score 0):

You are casting `imageView` in wrong way. Add this lines inside the `onCreate()` of your Navigation Drawer Activity.

```
NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
View view = navigationView.getHeaderView(0);
ImageView yourProfileImageView=(ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.userProfilePicture);
```

and then

```
yourProfileImageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            Intent intent = new Intent(v.getContext(),ProfileActivity.class);

            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
```

Now by clicking only on ImageView in your navigation header you can start new activity.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to start fragment from activity.The app will crash automatically. So you should use below code in onClick method of the imageview.

Then do this in your activity to add fragment:

```
FragmentManager manager = getFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction transaction = manager.beginTransaction();
transaction.add(R.id.container,new Profile(),YOUR_FRAGMENT_STRING_TAG);
transaction.addToBackStack(null);
transaction.commit();
```

And to replace fragment do this:

```
FragmentManager manager = getFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction transaction = manager.beginTransaction();
transaction.replace(R.id.container,new Profile(),YOUR_FRAGMENT_STRING_TAG);
transaction.addToBackStack(null);
transaction.commit();
```

Here container is the id of the frameLayout